# gstreamer play H.264 from RTP with audio (MP4)

Tags: video, gstreamer, h.264, rtp, raspberry-pi2

I spent a lot of time experimenting with gstreamer. I became sad because there is nowhere a simple and good explanation of some interesting features of it. My problem is as follows:

I have a desktop on one side and a raspberry (series 2) on another.
Playing FHD videos on rpi works like a charm with omxplayer.

What I wanted is to stream some of my video files
*(Audio Type: AAC LC Stereo, Video Type: 1920×816 (1080p) ~ 24 fps)*
to my raspberry and play them.
Where I got so far is only videoplayback with following commands:

**DESKTOP:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=PATH_TO.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc !
rtph264pay ! udpsink host=IP_ADDR port=NUMBER
```

**RPi:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=PORT caps="application/x-rtp, media=
(string)video, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse
! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! eglglessink
```

Videoplayback is not really fluent but at least it works. I can't say anything about audio because every query I tried didn't work and I decided to capitulate...

I will be very thankful and glad if someone had same issue like me and could help me resolving it.
*(and maybe there is a better solution possible to play fhd fluent from eth0)*

*I don't want to use XBMC or network share because I use this rpi for other things to and I would like to know if it is possible with gstreamer, vlc or anything else*

Answer (score 0):

You need a jitterbuffer before your depayloader. rtpbin if you are going to do both audio and video.